# Vcpkg port throws error as ninja can't find target "install"

Tags: cmake, vcpkg

So I'm currently working on the setup of a small vcpkg registry by myself. For testing I tried to create a small package to publish. Yet when I want to integrate this package via vcpkg an error arises due to ninja not recognizing the install argument/target. Does anybody now want is expected for this command to work? I already did include install() statements and an `install` target does show up in vs, yet still....

An initial thought on my behalf was that maybe the naming of the project and target is screwed up so I named the target exactly like the project. This did not help though...

Comment: "an error arises due to ninja not recognizing the install argument/target." - Do not *describe* the error, instead add to the question post its **exact** text.